Constrain return type to be subtype of this
I have the following interface:
internal interface ITyped<EnumType> where EnumType : struct, Enum
{
    public EnumType Type { get; }

    // !!! this method must always return a subtype* of the implementing class
    internal static Type TypeFromEnum(EnumType value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

I need the method TypeFromEnum to always return a type that is a subtype* of the implementing class. Is there a way to write that condition down in code, maybe with some kind of where constraint ?
(*) By "subtype" I mean either the class type itself or a real child type, so something that could be captured by where Sub : Base if Sub and Base were type parameters.

Use case: I have a bunch of classes with a one-level inheritance hierarchy
public class A { ... }
public class A1 : A { ... }
public class A2 : A { ... }
public class A3 : A { ... }

public abstract class B { ... }
public class B1 { ... }
public class B2 { ... }

and I need to (de-)serialize them from/to json using System.Text.Json. In order to make that possible, A and B have a Type property of some enum type. For deserialization I have a custom converter that reads the content of that type entry as an enum, and then calls TypeFromEnum to determine which type it should deserialize to. Here are the enums and relevant content of the classes:
public enum AType { a, a1, a2, a3 }

public enum BType { b1, b2 }


public class A : ITyped<AEnum>
{
    public AEnum Type { get; }
    internal static Type TypeFromEnum(AEnum value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case AType.a: return typeof(A);
            case AType.a1: return typeof(A1);
            case AType.a2: return typeof(A2);
            case AType.a3: return typeof(A3);
            default: throw new InvalidOperationException(); // should never be called
        }
    }
    ...
}


public abstract class B : ITyped<BEnum>
{
    public BEnum Type { get; }
    internal static Type TypeFromEnum(BEnum value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case BType.b1: return typeof(B1);
            case BType.b2: return typeof(B2);
            default: throw new InvalidOperationException(); // should never be called
        }
    }
    ...
}


why is simply instance.GetType() not an option?

@IvanPetrov I do not see how instance.GetType() could be incorporated into a type constraint. Can you elaborate?

you have an instance and you want to know its type is - isn't the easiest way to just call GetType on it? just why would you need the enums at all?

@IvanPetrov No, I don't have an instance. I have a json that I want to deserialize, polymorphically. For that I need the enums.

yeah, I think I managed to get my head around it.

I think it's an XY question. Here the answer to X

@Orace Thanks for the hint. Finally! When I wrote my code, System.Text.Json could not do that. Unfortunately, I still need to work this out because we have to work with .net481.

By the way, with this implementation, enums are not valid type discriminator

how do you call TypeFromEnum exactly ?

@IvanPetrov Inside my self-implemented JsonConverter<BaseType> subclass in the Read and Write methods. public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BaseType value, JsonSerializerOptions options) { var type = _TypeFromEnum(value.Type); ... }. For Read it's too complicated/long to paste that here, since it is not the issue of my question.

so you are not calling the static interface method like A.TypeFromEnum? How is the invocation even possible

TypeFromEnum returns a System.Type instance, which contains information about a type at runtime. There's no way to put any constraint on that at compile time.

@IvanPetrov Ah, I forgot half of it. _TypeFromEnum is a property of the converter which is set on converter creation. The converter has type parameters; among them the BaseType. From there it gets the static TypeFromEnum method and sets it to its _TypeFromEnum property.

@Kjara so you are passing the A as BaseType generic parameter and you are effecitvely invoking A.TypeFromEnum?

@IvanPetrov yes.

Why can't you just have a Default Interface Method directly on the interface internal static Type TypeFromEnum() => return typeof(EnumType);

@Charlieface because the value of the enum type holds which subtype we have, we are not interested in its type

@Kjara I know you have already accepted an answer, but I think mine actually answers the question with minimal overhead (latest version should be clear in how to use it)

If we rely on the switch-case statement in the implementations of TypeFromEnum to provide us the type based on the enum value (as the other answer does), we can still enforce compile time safety from this point forward by changing the signature to return a custom IAssignableTo<out T> instead of Type.
We need two additional types to achieve that:
public class TypeOf<T> : IAssignableTo<T> {
    public Type Type => typeof(T);
}

public interface IAssignableTo<out T> {
    Type Type { get; }
}

They help us exploit interface covariance which fits your requirement for "subtypes" (will be clear how in the example below)
We then rewrite the interface to accept another generic parameter ClassType that we constrain to types that implement this interface. This help us change the return type of TypeFromEnum to IAssignableTo<ClassType> from Type.  A value of the interface IAssignableTo<ClassType> has a Type property which will get us the type instance via typeof(ClassType) ( see implementation above).
internal interface ITyped<EnumType, ClassType> 
    where EnumType : struct, Enum
    where ClassType: ITyped<EnumType, ClassType> {
    public EnumType Type { get; }

    // !!! this method must always return a subtype* of the implementing class -> it does now
    internal static IAssignableTo<ClassType> TypeFromEnum(EnumType value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

and the implementation:
public enum AType { a, a1, a2, a3 }

public class B { }

public class A1 : A { }

public class A : ITyped<AType, A> {
    public AType Type { get; }

    internal static IAssignableTo<A> TypeFromEnum(AType value) {
        switch (value) {
            case AType.a: return new TypeOf<A>();

            // IAssignableTo<A> covariance here allows us to return
            // TypeOf<A1> for a value of IAssignableTo<A>
            case AType.a1: return new TypeOf<A1>();

            //CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeOf<B>'
            // to 'IAssignableTo<A>'. 
            // An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
            case AType.a2: return new TypeOf<B>(); // compile time error


            default: throw new InvalidOperationException(); // should never be called
        }
    }
}

To consume you just need to call the Type property of the returned value:
IAssignableTo<A> typeOf = A.TypeFromEnum(AType.a1);
Type aType = typeOf.Type;

in your use case maybe where A is BaseType generic parameter to another class:
IAssignableTo<BaseType> typeOf = _TypeFromEnum(value.Type);
Type baseType = typeOf.Type;

this helps us eliminate the runtime check from the other answer:
public Type SafeTypeFromEnum(EnumTypevalue value)
{
    var result = TypeFromEnum(value);
    if (!result.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EnumTypevalue)))
        throw new Exception();

    return result;
}


There is no way to force a method to return a variable matching a certain criterion.
It's like having this interface:
int GetOddRandomNumber();

The implementation can be:
public int GetOddRandomNumber() => 42;

And you can't do anything about it.
The solution is to wrap the call in a method that will validate the output:
public Type SafeTypeFromEnum(EnumTypevalue value)
{
    var result = TypeFromEnum(value);
    if (!result.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EnumTypevalue)))
        throw new Exception();

    return result;
}

